# Deploying a typescript app on heroku, execution error

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku

Since the start I am using Nodejs/Typescript to make the server.

I am trying to deploy to heroku, and saw that heroku was using the npm run build command, so my typescript should be built when i push on heroku branch from github.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./build/index.js",
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "local": "./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env tsnd --respawn app/main.ts --experimental-modules"
  },
```

when I deployed, I got no error, it built and then the server started. but when I used postman to execute some request, the server crashed with

```
2019-07-28T06:30:07.845261+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user ****@****.com
2019-07-28T06:30:11.641982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-07-28T06:30:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-07-28T06:30:13.889373+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-28T06:30:13.897111+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-28T06:30:13.700404+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-28T06:30:13.700432+00:00 app[web.1]: > NodeJsTest@1.0.0 start /app
2019-07-28T06:30:13.700434+00:00 app[web.1]: > set NODE_ENV=production && node build/index.js
2019-07-28T06:30:13.700435+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-28T06:30:13.803076+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2019-07-28T06:30:13.803079+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-07-28T06:30:13.803081+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-07-28T06:30:13.803082+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-28T06:30:13.803084+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/build/index.js'
```

Heroku is searching inside app/build but the build is on the root so it should just be like what I pass in the npm start ./build/index.js and not ./app/build/index.js

how can I pass an absolute path (I tried --prefix) ?

**EDIT 1 :** =>

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ../build/index.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./config/test.env jest --watch",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "local": "./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env tsnd --respawn app/main.ts --experimental-modules"
  },
```

tsconfig

```
"outDir": "./build",  //which is root/build
```

LOGS

```
2019-07-28T07:21:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user *********@ymail.com
2019-07-28T07:22:31.835544+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f0745bf9 by user *********@ymail.com
2019-07-28T07:22:31.835544+00:00 app[api]: Release v15 created by user *********@ymail.com
2019-07-28T07:22:32.307702+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-28T07:22:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-07-28T07:22:35.686869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-07-28T07:22:37.742582+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-28T07:22:37.568640+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-07-28T07:22:37.568660+00:00 app[web.1]: > NodeJsTest@1.0.0 start /app
2019-07-28T07:22:37.568661+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ../build/index.js
2019-07-28T07:22:37.568663+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-28T07:22:37.659479+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2019-07-28T07:22:37.659483+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-07-28T07:22:37.659484+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-07-28T07:22:37.659486+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-28T07:22:37.659488+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/build/index.js'
2019-07-28T07:22:37.659490+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2019-07-28T07:22:37.659491+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2019-07-28T07:22:37.659496+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
2019-07-28T07:22:37.659498+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-07-28T07:22:37.659500+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
2019-07-28T07:22:37.664783+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-07-28T07:22:37.665151+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-07-28T07:22:37.666157+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! NodeJsTest@1.0.0 start: `node ../build/index.js`
2019-07-28T07:22:37.666264+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-07-28T07:22:37.666520+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-07-28T07:22:37.666699+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the NodeJsTest@1.0.0 start script.
2019-07-28T07:22:37.666855+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-07-28T07:22:37.671035+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-28T07:22:37.671225+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-07-28T07:22:37.671348+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-07-28T07_22_37_667Z-debug.log
2019-07-28T07:22:37.723807+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-07-28T07:22:39.173088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/%20/user/signup" host=nodejstest-cg.herokuapp.com request_id=c2a706e6-c1bf-420e-ab0b-19b659382a65 fwd="222.224.213.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-07-28T07:31:43.547336+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-28T07:31:46.909924+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-07-28T07:31:49.187641+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-28T07:31:49.015302+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-28T07:31:49.015323+00:00 app[web.1]: > NodeJsTest@1.0.0 start /app
2019-07-28T07:31:49.015326+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ../build/index.js
2019-07-28T07:53:09.288766+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-07-28T07:53:09.289903+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! NodeJsTest@1.0.0 start: `node ../build/index.js`
2019-07-28T07:53:09.290066+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-07-28T07:53:09.290318+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-07-28T07:53:09.290501+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the NodeJsTest@1.0.0 start script.
2019-07-28T07:53:09.290663+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-07-28T07:53:09.308332+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-28T07:53:09.308545+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-07-28T07:53:09.308683+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-07-28T07_53_09_291Z-debug.log
2019-07-28T07:53:09.362302+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

**EDIT 2 =>**

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./build/index.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./config/test.env jest --watch",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "local": "./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env tsnd --respawn app/main.ts --experimental-modules"
  },
```

logs :

```
2019-07-28T09:02:50.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user **********@ymail.com
2019-07-28T09:04:05.823031+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-28T09:04:05.656792+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 2df838c6 by user **********@ymail.com
2019-07-28T09:04:05.656792+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user **********@ymail.com
2019-07-28T09:04:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-07-28T09:04:09.723166+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-07-28T09:04:12.659767+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-07-28T09:04:12.676681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-28T09:04:12.436114+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-28T09:04:12.436142+00:00 app[web.1]: > NodeJsTest@1.0.0 start /app
2019-07-28T09:04:12.436144+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./build/index.js
2019-07-28T09:04:12.436146+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-28T09:04:12.582525+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2019-07-28T09:04:12.582529+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-07-28T09:04:12.582530+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-07-28T09:04:12.582532+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-28T09:04:12.582534+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/build/index.js'
2019-07-28T09:04:12.582539+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2019-07-28T09:04:12.582542+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2019-07-28T09:04:12.582543+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
2019-07-28T09:04:12.582546+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-07-28T09:04:12.582548+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
2019-07-28T09:04:12.592947+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-07-28T09:04:12.593499+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-07-28T09:04:12.594999+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! NodeJsTest@1.0.0 start: `node ./build/index.js`
2019-07-28T09:04:12.595105+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-07-28T09:04:12.595301+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-07-28T09:04:12.595420+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the NodeJsTest@1.0.0 start script.
2019-07-28T09:04:12.595588+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-07-28T09:04:12.603105+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-28T09:04:12.603332+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-07-28T09:04:12.603425+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-07-28T09_04_12_596Z-debug.log
2019-07-28T09:04:13.058556+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/%20/user/signup" host=nodejstest-cg.herokuapp.com request_id=c9a53a6d-a237-4da9-9439-697758c980cb fwd="222.224.213.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Have you tried to use two dots `../` so it looks like this `node ../build/index.js` ?

Comment: yes, it actually search on the good directory, but there is something I do wrong cause he is still not finding it. thanks

Comment: Can you show the logs when you push the solution on heroku? It seems you only scaled to web@1. When you push the solution on heroku, you should have these lines of log: `remote: Running build` and `remote: > npx tsc`.

Comment: @L.Meyer added full logs

Comment: There is an incoherence with your start, can you fix `"start": "node ../build/index.js"` by `"start": "node ./build/index.js"` and reedit your logs.

Comment: Ok by writing it for the 20 times I found out the idiot mistake it's main.ts ... therefore main.js... going to take a break for today lolz... thank you sorry for the waste of time. gonna try with main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced some issues when I deployed my React project using TypeScripts. So I found a way to resolve my issues is using Webpack. The Webpack will make a main.js file from your Typescript files, so Heroku can know what you deployed.

You can find more information here: [enter link description here](https://webpack.js.org/)